# trying to increment label string value

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am trying to increment string value by 1 after converting it into int type.
but it is concatenating string value not number.

```
Mail(email, "SUB", "Test body.:" + lbloText.InnerText + lblame.InnerText + lblNo.InnerText + "  with Revision:" + Convert.ToInt32( lblRevision.InnerText )+1 + " Has ben genrated");
```

in the above i am trying to increment  lblRevision.InnerText by 1 after converting it into int but it concates as string value is not incrementing.
Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: The + on the left side of `Convert.ToInt32` took precedence, so the string concatenation was performed first, add parenthesis to make it clear, `+ (Convert.ToInt32( lblRevision.InnerText )+1) +`

Answer (score 1):

Your Mail body is in string type.
Put `Convert.ToInt32( lblRevision.InnerText )+1` inside `()` and then parse to string again,

```
 ( Convert.ToInt32( lblRevision.InnerText ) + 1 ).ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `int.TryParse`: *increment* by `1` if text parsed as an integer, set `1` if not (say, in case of empty string):

```
$"...{(int.TryParse(lblRevision.InnerText, out var v) ? v + 1 : 1)}..."
```

**Code:**

```
Mail(
   email, 
  "SUB", 
 $"Test body.: {lbloText.InnerText}{lblame.InnerText}{lblNo.InnerText} with Revision: {(int.TryParse(lblRevision.InnerText, out var v) ? v + 1 : 1)} has been generated");
```

Another suggestion is to use *string interpolation* - `$"...{value1}...{value2}..."` instead of concatenations: `"..." + value1 + "..." + value2 + "..."`